# How to catch INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT Error?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap

I'm trying to create a trading bot and I noticed that even when a transaction is 100% gonna fail, the swapExactTokensForTokens still pushes through hence paying gas fee. My question is, how does Pancakeswap know that a transaction is gonna fail before executing it? How do we catch errors so that we don't have to pay gas fees for a transaction that's gonna fail?

[image: Pancakeswap Error]

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, you should be able to trigger this with `revert, require, assert`. The error `INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT` is like a string that is being returned when something is being violated on the contract side.

Comment: I'm trying to do a pre-blockchain check so that I don't have to pay for gas fees just to know if a transaction will fail or not. I'm not sure how uniswap does it though and I'm finding it hard to find information online.

Comment: Usually if a transaction will revert, it'll show up in metamask before the tx is submitted. This is the difference between the different error statements. For example, in the case of `assert` there is 0 gas refunded, whereas in the case of `require` all remaining gas is refunded if you try to force an invalid tx through. Not sure if this is what you meant!

Comment: I actually found out that estimateGas throws different exceptions and I think that has similar effect to how uniswap/pancakeswap check for errors before the transaction. I just thought that function would just return the estimated gas basing on its name so it was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

When calling [swapTokensForExactTokens](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L238) (see interface below) make sure that amountInMin is using [getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path)](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L427), as that is what the contract is checking against

[image]